# Renaming: Remove last X characters from files in directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename

I'm trying to rename a lot of videos downloaded via youtube-dl from various sources. As you may know, yt-dl will append the view code to the file name.

E.g.

> Video Title-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4

I'm looking for a program or CLI command for removing the X last characters from the filename. From the example, the number would be 12 characters (excluding file extension, .mp4)

I've tried searching around for such a command, but havent found any which worked. Also tried KReename, but could not find the equivalent of "Delete X characters starting at Last character", which I remember a Windows program I once used had.

Are there any "simple" commands with which to do this? Alternatively a program, or some setting in KRename. Tried PyRename, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`prename`**(*Perl* rename) command:

```
prename 's/(.*).{12}(\.mp4)/$1$2/' *.mp4
```

Comment: @EdwardAlekos, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*)?(#c12).mp4' '$1.mp4'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) when happy).

Answer (score 2):

One way to think of this is you want to remove the last 16 characters including extension,
so you could use [bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) [parameter expansion](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) to do this:

> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
>   **Substring  Expansion**
>   .  Expands to up to
>   *`length`*
>   characters of the value of
>   *`parameter`*
>   starting at the character specified by
>   *`offset`*
>   .  If
>   *`parameter`*
>   is
>   **`@`**
>   , an
>   indexed array subscripted by
>   **`@`**
>   or
>   **`*`**
>   , or an associative array name, the results differ as described below.  If
>   *`length`*
>   is omitted, expands to the substring
>   of  the value of
>   *`parameter`*
>   starting at the character specified by
>   *`offset`*
>   and extending to the end of the value.
>   *`length`*
>   and
>   *`offset`*
>   are arithmetic expressions (see
>   **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**
>   [below]).
>
> If *`offset`* evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset in characters from the end of the value of *`parameter`*. 
> If *`length`* evaluates
> to  a  number less than zero, it is interpreted as an offset in characters from the end of the value of *`parameter`* rather than a number of characters, and
> the expansion is the characters between *`offset`* and that result.  Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least  one  space  to
> avoid being confused with the **`:-`** expansion.

Given the part about needing a space after the colon for negative numbers, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mp4; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f:0: -16}.mp4"
done

exit
```

You might want to test this
by first doing `echo mv -- "$f" "${f:0: -16}.mp4"`,
and then taking out the `echo` when the dry run produces acceptable results. 
(Beware that support for negative *`length`*
is a *relatively* recent addition to Bash; YMMV.)

Note that, if you have `A Star is Born-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4`
and `A Star is Born-foobar42quuxBAZ.mp4`,
then they will both be renamed to `A Star is Born.mp4`
(i.e., there will be a “collision”). 
If you are running `mv` unadorned,
then the first file will get clobbered when the second one is renamed. 
You might want to use `mv -i` to protect against this.

Comment: You don’t actually need the space in the substring expansion, because you have a negative *`length`,* and it’s necessary only when there is a negative *`offset`.*

Answer (score 1):

In KRemane, on the "Filename" tab, select "Custom name". 
You can write something like this:

```
[1-[#length-12]]
```

where 12 represent the number of characters it will remove
from the right of the filename. 
With the button on the right (i), you can get a bit more information about the regular expressions use for that application.

Comment: (1) Can you link to current documentation for KRename? I’m having trouble finding any …  (1a) … and the krename.net home page seems to be shut down. Do you know whether this program is still being maintained and/or supported? (2) I know that it’s unreasonable to ask you to post the entire KRename manual (if there is such a thing) but can you at least provide a little explanation for the command / pattern that you suggested? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Have you actually tested this and verified that it works? (3a) Do you need the ‘`#`’?  From [the documentation I have been able to find](https://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/krename/Documentation/3.0.12/krename-3.0.12.pdf?viasf=1#page=12), it looks like “``[1-[length-12]]``” might be good enough.

Comment: That option is in fact under  *Filename* (tab) – *Simple Filename* (tab) – *Filename* (dropdown): *Custom name*. Note that the last options used are remembered (after restarting krename) under *Filename* (tab) – *Advanced Filename* (tab) – *Template* (dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

Thunar bulk rename tool (`thunar -B`).

[image]

KRename cannot do this. There is a sort of incomplete fork of Thunar's renamer, made for KDE, but which can be used separately, called "[Bionic Batch Renamer](https://github.com/Nomen-Luni/Bionic-Batch-Renamer)"). It lacks some basic options (remembering settings, re-arranging items in list).

---

There is this problem with Thunar renamer that it comes with Thunar file manager and other xfce tools. Thunar can interfere with the default file manager on Plasma KDE: I use [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1430542/925128).

---

As a complementary answer to [the one on the option `[1-[#length-12]]` in  Krename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715115/341192):

That option is in fact under  *Filename* (tab) – *Simple Filename* (tab) – *Filename* (dropdown): *Custom name*.

[image]

Note that the last options used are remembered (after restarting krename) under *Filename* (tab) – *Advanced Filename* (tab) – *Template* (dropdown).

[image]